# Getting ERROR while WAR file deploying in tomcat7

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat7, spring-jdbc

I have spring mvc based application. That is running tomcat7 server. Recently i made a few changes in my application. I created war file for entire application again. And i try to redeploy the new war file in tomcat7 server. When i click on my domain name i am getting "the requested page not available".

Why this error coming. I given all the properties file values correctly. could you please help me?

This is the production application. I used Linux servers and MySQL DB. Tomcat7, spring mvc and spring jdbc.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens due jdk version. In my production server have jdk 1.7 but in my local i have jdk 1.8. I created war file with jdk 1.8 version. That's why i am getting that error. now i changed jdk version and recreate war file and deployed in server. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you are configured incorrect endpoint/url in application. Since the error is 4o4. Kindly revisit your routing configuration. It doesn't look the issue of database also.

Comment: I checked all are configurations and database connections. All are correct position. I tried to deploy the war file stage environment, it's working fine. but in production it's not working.